# Call to a member function save() on a non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I am building a small laravel app beginning level. I got error in code in I couldn't solve out.
Here is the code

post model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('app\user');
    }
}
```

user model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class user extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
  use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
  public function posts()
  {
    $this->hasMany('app\post');
  }
}
```

postcontroller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class postcontroller extends Controller{
  public function postCreatePost(Request $request){
    $post = new post();
    $post->body = $request['body'];
    $request->user()->posts()->save($post);
    return redirect()->route('dashboard');
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for any try from you to solve this query.

Comment: where is user model?

Comment: I edited the post !!

Comment: do a dd on $user inside postCreatePost() method and whats the output?

Comment: how to do a dd,I am biginner..

Comment: ok justt do this  inside postCreatePost() befor return redirect() add code 'dd($request->user());'and run

Comment: user {#195 ▼
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:7 [▶]
  #original: array:7 [▶]
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}

Comment: did it solve the problem?

Comment: not woking dude..be dd i found may be 'user_id' and another column 'id' mismatching..I am trying on it.

Comment: just copy paste your dd values in question after expanding attributes array and original array. is dd showing the same as the logged in user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure inside your user model you're returning the relationship.

```
class user extends Model implements Authenticatable
{
   use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
   public function posts()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('app\post');
   }
}
```

Your posted code doesn't have a `return` inside the `posts` function.

Comment: You're missing the "return" in it

Comment: hehe.. this was nice :)

Answer (score 1):

i think this should fix

add your table field to  protected $fillable = [] array

user

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['body'];

    public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('app\user');
    }
}
```

post

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class user extends Model implements Authenticatable
{

  use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

  protected $fillable = ['username', 'field2', 'blabla'];

  public function posts()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('app\post');
  }
}
```

postcontroller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class postcontroller extends Controller{
  public function postCreatePost(Request $request){
    $post = new post(['body' => $request->body]);
    $request->user->posts()->save($post);
    return redirect()->route('dashboard');
  }
}
```

Comment: MassAssignmentException in model!!

Comment: add your table fields to fillable array in models

Comment: thank you so much for your help...but I am missing return in model..and now it works:) thank you for dd such a gud guy u r!!